# Largest Convex polygon consisting of k points

Tags: geometry, polygons

The problem is Given a set of points, determinate the Largest (in terms of area) Polygon consisting of **at most** $k$ points.

In a shape like The one below:

[image: Shape]

$k = 3,polygon =A,F,G $

I would like to know if there is a way to do this. (not choosing any $3\ldots k$ points and test)

Comment: This, Sir, is a very good question. What is known of each point? Their coordinates (if you're using that) or the distance of one to another?

Comment: I imagine you'd start with the convex hull and start clipping off ears. There may be a proof out there.

Comment: @GustavoMarra Their Coordinates are known.

Comment: There is not a unique solution to this.  Take 8 points evenly spaced on a circle, there are seven 7 sided polygons using 7 points, all of which give maximum area.  Does this make a difference in your question?

Answer (score 0):

For $k=3$ an algorithm as follows may help:
Select two points, e.g. $A,B$.
Determine the point farthest away from the line $AB$. That would be $F$, so now you have $ABF$. Drop the first point, so you have $B,F$.
Determine the point farthest away from the line $BF$. That would be $G$, so now you have $BFG$. Drop the first point, so you now have $F,G$.
Determine the point farthest away from the line $FG$. That would be $A$, so now you have $FGA$.
If you continued further, you'd not get any improvement and stick with $FGA$.

Finding the point farthes away takes $O(n)$. If I'm not mistaken, a point may be rejected and selected again (as happened with $A$ above) at most twice, so the total running time is $O(n^2)$ and thus faster than $O(n^3)$ brute force.

I am not sure, however, how to generalize this to $k>3$.

Comment: I tried to choose a point then choosing the farthest $k-1$ points from it, but there was a case that countered this technique.